# Iteration for columns cleaning with similar name

Tags: r

I am performing a column cleaning, most of the columns have same cleaning operations and have same names with only the last character being in increasing order. I want a way to iterate them to save time.

For example:

i.e columns names BB1,BB2, BB3, BB4

```
US1$BB2 <- ifelse(US1$BB2 == 1,1, ifelse(US1$BB2 == 2,0,NA))

US1$BB3 <- ifelse(US1$BB3 == 1,1, ifelse(US1$BB3 == 2,0,NA))
```

how would we make it more efficient?

Comment: Not sure what you are trying `ifelse` but maybe you can try `gsub('\\D', '', names(US1))` which will give you only the numbers in column names.

Comment: Maybe an example of what you want to do along with expected output would help clarifying things. This post might help to provide that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269

Answer (score 1):

You could select all the columns that you want to do this to, and perform the calculation on all of them simultaneously. i.e.

```
#Example data
US1 <- data.frame(N=letters[1:5], BB1=1:5,BB2=5:1, BB3=1, BB4=2)
US1
# N BB1 BB2 BB3 BB4
# 1 a   1   5   1   2
# 2 b   2   4   1   2
# 3 c   3   3   1   2
# 4 d   4   2   1   2
# 5 e   5   1   1   2

#Select the columns that you want to transform:
columns <- paste0("BB", 1:4) #Columns BB1 - BB4
#or 
columns <- grepl("^BB", colnames(US1)) #All columns starting with BB

US1[,columns] <- ifelse(US1[,columns]==1, 1, ifelse(US1[,columns]==2, 0, NA))

US1
# N BB1 BB2 BB3 BB4
# 1 a   1  NA   1   0
# 2 b   0  NA   1   0
# 3 c  NA  NA   1   0
# 4 d  NA   0   1   0
# 5 e  NA   1   1   0
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Miff's example dataset

```
library(tidyverse)

US1 <- data.frame(N=letters[1:5], BB1=1:5,BB2=5:1, BB3=1, BB4=2)
```

Create a cleaning function

```
clean <- function(x) {
  case_when(
    x == 1 ~ 1,
    x == 2 ~ 0
  )
}
```

You can use `mutate_at` to apply a function to particular columns

```
US1 %>%
  mutate_at(vars(starts_with("BB")), clean)
#>   N BB1 BB2 BB3 BB4
#> 1 a   1  NA   1   0
#> 2 b   0  NA   1   0
#> 3 c  NA  NA   1   0
#> 4 d  NA   0   1   0
#> 5 e  NA   1   1   0
```

Or, you can use the newer `across` function to do the same thing

```
US1 %>%
  mutate(across(starts_with("BB"), clean))
#>   N BB1 BB2 BB3 BB4
#> 1 a   1  NA   1   0
#> 2 b   0  NA   1   0
#> 3 c  NA  NA   1   0
#> 4 d  NA   0   1   0
#> 5 e  NA   1   1   0
```